# How to update additional packages?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

After login, I get:

```
3 software packages can be updated
0 of these updates are security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

New release '20.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

Trying release upgrade I get:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

**How can I update these three additional packages?**

It’s true, `sudo apt list --upgradable` shows at least two packages being updatable (bonus question, why not three?):

```
$ sudo apt list --upgradable
Auflistung... Fertig
base-files/bionic-updates 10.1ubuntu2.10 amd64 [aktualisierbar von: 10.1ubuntu2.8]
ubuntu-server/bionic-updates 1.417.5 amd64 [aktualisierbar von: 1.417.4]
```

However, `apt-get update` does not install them:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Paketaktualisierung (Upgrade) wird berechnet... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete sind zurückgehalten worden:
  base-files ubuntu-server
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 2 nicht aktualisiert.
```

In English: *Two packages have been hold back.* (Bonus question: why?)

In just guessing I tried a `sudo apt-get update --all` but that command is unknown.

How do I get the missing packages to install?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the packages manually to the command line solved the problem for me.

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade base-files ubuntu-server
[…]
Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden installiert:
  motd-news-config
Die folgenden Pakete werden aktualisiert (Upgrade):
  base-files ubuntu-server
2 aktualisiert, 1 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
[…]
```

Surprisingly, this gives two updates and one new installed package, making it three packages being updated.